# When i have multiple VM hosts using NAT, does that mean all of them are behind a single virtual router or each of them have a dedicated router?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

So in a networking perspective, when i run many hosts on my VMware and set all of them to use NAT, does it mean that each of them are behind a virtual router that is using NAT or all of them are behind a single router?

And if i want them to communicate do they need to be in the same subnet or..?

and a side question : lets say machine A uses host only and machine B uses NAT, does this mean A is connected to a router and that router to B, therefore i need to use port forwarding if i want A to connect to a web host at B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your main question

A virtual network is like a local physical network.  If you configure a VM to use NAT, you're actually just setting it to use a virtual network (by default, VMnet8) preconfigured for NAT.  VMware Workstation supports configuring only one virtual network for NAT.  Therefore all VMs configured to use NAT will all be on the same network (and therefore be able to communicate with each other, assuming that there are no firewalls in the respective guests blocking traffic).

**TL;DR:** Yes, all VMs configured to use NAT will be behind a single virtual router.

---

### Your side question

If you configure a VM to use host-only networking, as with NAT, you're actually just setting it to use a virtual network (VMnet1) preconfigured for host-only networking.  Separate virtual networks are like separate physical networks; there is no connection between the host-only network and the NAT network.  If you want A to communicate with B without putting A on the NAT network, then you'll need to create a LAN segment or custom virtual network between A and B to bridge them.

**TL;DR:** No, there is not any kind of virtual router hierarchy.  There are only separate virtual networks.